# Upgrading from Delphi 2005 to 2010 libeay32.dll

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010, rsa

I'm upgrading my program from Delphi 2005 to Delphi 2010.
I'm having a problem with RSA functions

The following procedure work's well under D2005, but with D2010 the result is always nil.
I allready tried with new version of libeay32.dll

```
function ReadPrivateKey(AFileName: TFileName): pEVP_PKEY;
var
  keyfile: pBIO;
  a : pEVP_PKEY;
begin
  a := nil;
  keyfile := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  BIO_read_filename(keyfile,   PAnsiChar(AFilename));
  result := PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(keyfile, a, nil, nil);
  if result = nil then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('Não foi possível ler a chave privada.');
  end;
  BIO_free(keyfile);
end;
```

Does anyone had this problem?
Thanks
Sam

Comment: I guess this is most likely a Unicode-related issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get a warning W1044 "Suspicious typecast of TFileName to PAnsiChar".

You're typecasting `TFileName` (which is an alias for `string` and in Delphi 2010 this is `UnicodeString`) **directly** to `PAnsiChar`.
I guess that already `BIO_read_filename` fails; you don't check the returned value. According to the [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_file.html), it expects UTF8-encoded string, so try encoding it with [UTF8Encode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/System.UTF8Encode):

```
BIO_read_filename(keyfile, PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(AFileName)));
```

Comment: if it really does take utf8 then the code was broken even in delphi 2005en the code was broken even in delphi 2005

Comment: @David Yes, Delphi 2005 was still ANSI so by coincidence it would work for the file names whose UTF8-encoded representation is the same ANSI string.

Comment: @Samuel You are likely to run into lots more of these issues. I suggest you read Marco Cantu's white paper on Unicode Delphi and review your code in light of that.